# How to place breadcrumb under Bootstrap3 jumbotron in Django CMS?

Tags: django, django-cms, breadcrumbs

How to place breadcrumb under jumbotron? In `base.html` there is {% block content %} where jumbotron is being called. But if I add inside there

```
{% block breadcrumb %}
{% show_breadcrumb 0 "cms/breadcrumb.html" 0 %}
{% endblock %}
```

then nothing shows. 
I've tried to insert that in `feature.html` page like this:
...

```
{% block content %}
   <div class="jumbotron>
      {% placeholder "feature" %}
   </div>
   <div class="breadcrumb">
      {% block breadcrumb %}
      {% endblock %}
   </div>
   <div>
      {% placeholder "content" %}
   </div>
{% endblock %}
```

But this magic don't shows breadcrumbs :-(

UPD: only thing that is shown is an empty row under jumbotron (in case if I add breadcrumb in `feature.html` as wrote above).

Answer (score 1):

Its should be:

```
{% show_breadcrumb 0 "menu/breadcrumb.html" 0 %}
```

i.e `show_breadcrumb` with an underscore.

Docs: http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/navigation.html#show-breadcrumb

Comment: It's typo, in my question here. I checked code, there is show_breadcrump. And no luck so far. 
Breadcrumb shows normally if I put code somewhere before content or after that. But the question is how to put breadcrumbs inside content, under jumbotron with image slider in that.

Answer (score 0):

Holy crap, I made it! 
I just added `{% load cms_tags staticfiles sekizai_tags menu_tags thumbnail %}` at the beggining of `feature.html` and changed a little bit code:

```
    <div class="breadcrumb">
        {% block breadcrumb %}
        {% show_breadcrumb 0 "cms/breadcrumb.html" 0 %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
```

Now breadcrumbs shown under jumbotron with slider. Nice!